# Magento 2 - Shipping rates issue

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.4

In my magento 2.4 store, I have enabled **Free shipping** and **Table rates** delivery methods.
Free shipping for only India country and added table rates form some countries.
Added sort order 1 for Free shipping and 2 for Table rates.

Whenever customer add one product to cart and move to checkout page, before filling shipping form, shipping rates showing for USA ( table rates ) and after fill form with India country rates showing zero, but I want to display free shipping by default.

Is there any setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

To change default country shipping rate, need to update tax configuration ( even no tax applying on products )

For this Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Default Tax Destination Calculation and update default country to India.

Now default rate showing for India ( Free shipping ) as I wanted.